# Return List<object> from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, chart.js

I'm working on a line chart using Chartjs and I'm getting a error from my webservice.  Here is the code for the service:

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<object> getProgram12Months(string usersessionid)
    {
        List<object> iData = new List<object>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();

        //First get distinct Month Name for select Year.
        string query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT TimeFrame FROM dbo.CSQ_ProgramCount12Months ORDER BY TimeFrame ";

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dtLabels = ds.Tables[0];


        foreach (DataRow drow in dtLabels.Rows)
        {
            labels.Add(drow["TimeFrame"].ToString());
        }
        iData.Add(labels);

        return iData;
    }
```

When I call the method from a browser I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   may not be used in this context.

I'm basing it [off this](https://codepedia.info/chart-js-asp-net-dynamically-create-line-chart-with-database-ms-sql-using-jquery-ajax-c-example/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is not serializable to web method instead of this you can return object[].

```
[WebMethod]
    public object[] getProgram12Months(string usersessionid)
    {
        List<object> iData = new List<object>();
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();

        //First get distinct Month Name for select Year.
        string query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT TimeFrame FROM dbo.CSQ_ProgramCount12Months ORDER BY TimeFrame ";

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dtLabels = ds.Tables[0];


        foreach (DataRow drow in dtLabels.Rows)
        {
            labels.Add(drow["TimeFrame"].ToString());
        }
        iData.Add(labels.ToArray());

        return iData.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is I need to add in the data for the chart too.  This is just the label and I will need to add nine more List<objects> to build the chart.

Comment: You can use dictionary instead like Dictionary<string, List<string>> so you can add many list in above dictionary and access each one by its key name

Comment: I get the following when I try it that way:
System.NotSupportedException: The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Comment: List or Dictionary is not serializable to web method so I converted it to return object array. I updated my answer. Kindly view it carefully and let me know

Comment: That returns:  System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.String[] may not be used in this context.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by creating two classes an populating them.  Thank you er-sho, your posts help lead me in the right direction.

```
public class ChartData2
    {
        public List<string> Legends;
        public List<int> AD;


    }

    public class Legend
    {
        public List<string> Months;
    }
```

Comment: Wow that's great, finally your problem has been solved. You please add related detail in your answer so it will be helpful to future reader or you can edit my answer to add such details. Choice is yours :)